# Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product - showing wrong version of program

Tags: powershell

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product  | where-object { $_.name -like "*OfficeScan*" }
```

Shows me the wrong version number of the TrendMicro OfficeScan Client - the default Version `12.0.1222` when the installed version is `12.0.4430`.

I also tried:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
```

There it doesnt show up at all. It's weird because in the old systemcontrol if i go to deinstallation it shows the correct version:

[image: deinstallation]

So I need to somehow extract the information of the actual version to my powershell. I need it for a auto update feature, it has to be using powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a 64bit system, you're looking in the [wrong place in the registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx).

I don't have TrendMicro, so using Adobe Reader as an example:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "*Adobe Reader*" } |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion
```

If you just want a numerical `Version` property to use as a comparison, update:

```
Select-Object -Expand DisplayVersion
```

Comment: It worked thank you, can you explain to me what the difference is?

Between  HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ and 
HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

Comment: Check the link in my answer as it explains that :)